# Posting a comment via Javascript API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I'm trying to post a comment using the javascript API.  I first get the list of comments for a particular `url`:

```
FB.api('/fql', {q: {
  query0: 'SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url="'+url+'"',
  query1: 'SELECT post_fbid, fromid, text, time, comments FROM comment WHERE object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM #query0) ORDER BY time DESC',
  query2: 'SELECT id, name FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT fromid FROM #query1)'
}}, function(resp) {
  ...
});
```

Then I can post to either the `comments_fbid` for the page or the `post_fbid` to respond to an existing post in the comment list.  These are represented by `id` below:

```
FB.login(function(resp) {
  if (!resp.authResponse) return;
  FB.api('/'+id+'/comments', 'post', {message: 'Hello World', function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
  });
}, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
```

If I post in reply to an existing message (i.e., to `post_fbid`), it works fine, but if I post to the top-level comments list (i.e., `comments_fbid`), I get an error:

```
{error: {code: 1, message: "An unknown error has occurred.", type: "OAuthException"}}
```

Comment: Quote docs: _“comments_fbid – The object_id associated with comments plugin comments for this url.”_ – sounds to me as if this is only an identifier for a comment box plugin instance, but nothing that you can actually “comment” on.

Comment: Is there another id I should be posting to instead?

Comment: What exactly do you want to post to? An outside URL as an Open Graph Object is AFAIK not an object you can directly “comment” on – the link has to be shared by someone first, before there can be comments on that post afterwards. Maybe you want to make a new _post_ instead of a comment, containing that particular URL …?

Comment: I want to reproduce the functionality in the comments widget, so I suppose I would need the `link_id` of the link generated when a comments widget is placed on a page.  Is this how the comments widget does it?